# How to change the range values in Qliksens

Tags: qliksense

I am practicing on how to use Qliksense and I came across this problem. I want to change the range values for the y-axis to show the difference in the **Number of Sales** between Year 2016 and Year 2017, which have values 105004 and 105609 respectively. However, as the values are too close to each other, I have been trying to find out how to change the values for the y-axis so that the graph will be able to show the difference in the **Number of Sales** between Year 2016 and Year 2017 more clearly. [The picture below shows the graph of the no. of sales between Year 2016 and Year 2017.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbEOv.png) Please kindly advice on how to change the range values.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Min value to reduce the range
The max value you can increase a bit for better formatting.

This will give you a better perception of the variation

[changing the min and max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1pkP.png)
[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAKry.png)